# CopyFromRecordSet has Invalid Cast Exception

Tags: excel, vb.net, dataset

I have a dataset produced from an SQL script and I am trying to output one column to a column in Excel.
The record set produces one column with a max of 228 records at any given time.

Currently this is the code that I am using (in the code i is the excel column number which is always set ):

```
myWkBook.Sheets(Row.Item("intTypeSort")).Cells(5, i).CopyFromRecordset(myResultsDS.Tables(0))
```

I am being thrown the error:

No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE))

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The way I've added a value to Excel is to do:
    `worksheet.Cells(5, i).value = "SomeValue"`

So you could loop through your DataSet and add the values manually.

I'm not to sure what Row.Item("intTypeSort") is trying to do.

Comment: I have got code that can cycle through the dataset and the rows and add that way but its very slow. The row.item("intTypeSort") is integer in the dataset to tell it which excel sheet to use.

Comment: You could convert the DataTable to a multidimensional array.  It will greatly speed it up.  Sorry can't help with the error that you're getting.